# Position relative is not repsonsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Well, I have this thing with position:relative; And then of course using top, left, bottom, and right to position. Well yeah I do that all the time go to the console, and change it manually and then put it in the actual css file. Well I love doing that, but here is the **MAJOR** issue. It is completely not responsive to changes in size. Let me show you a quick demo.

[image]
[image]

You can see the first picture, the topic icons which are like delete topic, edit, etc.. are all fine but as soon as you zoom in, you can see on the second image, it is completely messed up. Well here is my whole code for that page. I just really want a way that I can make the stuff responsive easily. Position:relative is easy but it doesn't give you a responsiveness unfortunately :(

**Minimal CSS:**

```
span.icon_share_topic {
    position: relative;
    /* left: 1422px; */
    /* top: 1048px; */
    margin-left: 60%;
}
span.icon_flag_topic {
    position: relative;
    left: 990px;
}
span.edit_topic_button {
    position: relative;
    right: -1087px;
    bottom: 8px;
}
span.bookmark_topic_button {
    position: relative;
    right: -958px;
}
span.replies_num_container {
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    left: 929px;
}
ng-md-icon.ng-scope.icon_reply_topic {
    top: -9px;
    position: relative;
    right: 2px;
}
button.md-icon-button.backward.md-button.ng-scope.md-ink-ripple {
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
}
span.delete_topic_button {
    position: relative;
    left: 1050px;
    bottom: 8px;
}
```

**Minimal HTML :**

```
  <div class="topic-buttons">
        <div class="topic-voting">
            <span class="vote-counting">
                {{countVote}} <span ng-if="currentAuthGet==null;"> Vote </span>
            </span>
            <span ng-if="currentAuthGet!=null;">
                <div class="vote-icons">
                    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Custom Icon Button" ng-click="upVote();">
                        <ng-md-icon icon="thumb_up" id="upVoteIcon" class="thumb-icon" size="20"></ng-md-icon>
                    </md-button>
                    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Custom Icon Button" ng-click="downVote();">
                        <ng-md-icon icon="thumb_down"  id="downVoteIcon" class="thumb-icon" size="20"></ng-md-icon>
                    </md-button>
                </div>  
            </span>
        </div>
         <span ng-if="deleteTopicPriv();">        
            <span class="delete_topic_button">
                <md-button class="md-icon-button">
                        <md-button class="md-icon-button animation-target" ng-click="deleteTopic()">
                            <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
                              Delete
                            </md-tooltip>
                            <ng-md-icon icon="delete" style="fill: #ff6400;" size="20"></ng-md-icon> 
                        </md-button>
                </md-button>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span ng-if="editTopicPriv();">        
            <span class="edit_topic_button">
                <md-button class="md-icon-button">
                        <md-button class="md-icon-button animation-target" ng-click="editTopic($event)">
                            <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
                              Edit
                            </md-tooltip>
                            <ng-md-icon icon="edit" style="fill: #ff6400;" size="20"></ng-md-icon> 
                        </md-button>
                </md-button>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span ng-if="currentAuthGet!=null;">        
            <span class="bookmark_topic_button">
                <md-button class="md-icon-button">
                        <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
                            Bookmark
                        </md-tooltip>
                        <span ng-if="bookMarkToggleTopic == true" ng-click="bookmarkClickOutlineTopic();">
                            <ng-md-icon icon="bookmark_outline" style="fill: #ff6400;" size="20"></ng-md-icon>
                        </span>
                        <span ng-if="bookMarkToggleTopic == false" ng-click="bookmarkClickNonOutlineTopic();">
                             <ng-md-icon icon="bookmark" style="fill: #009688;" size="20"></ng-md-icon>
                        </span>
                </md-button>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span ng-if="flagSee();">
           <span class="icon_flag_topic">
                    <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="">
                        <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
                            Flag
                        </md-tooltip>
                        <ng-md-icon icon="flag" style="fill: #ff6400;" size="20"></ng-md-icon> 
                    </md-button>
            </span>

        </span>
        <span class="icon_share_topic">
        <md-menu>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="openShareMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)">
                <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
                    Share
                </md-tooltip>
                <ng-md-icon icon="share" style="fill: #ff6400;" size="20"></ng-md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <md-menu-content width="4">
                <md-menu-item>
                    <md-button socialshare socialshare-provider="facebook" socialshare-text="Look at my post! Here : " socialshare-hashtags="angularjs, ng-forum, replies , programming" socialshare-url="{{urlSHARINGCURRENT}}">
                        <ng-md-icon icon="facebook-box" style="fill: #3b5998" size="20"></ng-md-icon>
                        Facebook
                    </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
                <md-menu-item>
                    <md-button socialshare socialshare-provider="twitter" socialshare-text="Look at my post! Here :" socialshare-hashtags="angularjs, ng-forum, replies , programming" socialshare-url="{{urlSHARINGCURRENT}}">
                        <ng-md-icon icon="twitter" style="fill: #0084b4" size="20"></ng-md-icon>
                        Twitter
                    </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
                <md-menu-item>
                    <md-button socialshare socialshare-provider="linkedin" socialshare-text="Ng-Forum Post" socialshare-description=" Look at my post! Here : {{urlSHARINGCURRENT}} " socialshare-source="angularjs, ng-forum, replies , programming" socialshare-url="{{urlSHARINGCURRENT}}">
                        <ng-md-icon icon="linkedin-box" style="fill: #007bb5" size="20"></ng-md-icon>
                        Linkedin
                    </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
                <md-menu-item>
                    <md-button socialshare socialshare-provider="google" socialshare-url="{{urlSHARINGCURRENT}}">
                        <ng-md-icon icon="google-plus-box" style="fill: #d34836" size="20"></ng-md-icon>
                        Google+
                    </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
            </md-menu-content>
        </md-menu>
        </span>
        <span ng-if="currentAuthGet!=null;">    
            <md-button class="md-raised md-accent" ng-click="replyTopic($event)">
                <ng-md-icon icon="reply" style="fill: #0affcf;" size="20" class="icon_reply_topic"></ng-md-icon>
                Reply
            </md-button>
        </span>
        <span ng-if="currentAuthGet==null;">
            <md-button class="md-raised md-accent" ng-click="notAuthReplyTopic()">
                <ng-md-icon icon="reply" style="fill: #0affcf;" size="20" class="icon_reply_topic"></ng-md-icon>
                Reply
            </md-button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

If you guys want more than just tabove code. Please say so, help would be greatly appreciated! Btw I'm working this [here](https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/ng-fourm). It would be awesome if we can work it out here to!

According to James Howell I did this for HTML:

```
 <span ng-if="flagSee();" class="container_flag_icon">
           <span class="icon_flag_topic">
                    <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="">
                        <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
                            Flag
                        </md-tooltip>
                        <ng-md-icon icon="flag" style="fill: #ff6400;" size="20"></ng-md-icon> 
                    </md-button>
            </span>

        </span>
```

And then this for CSS

```
span.container_flag_icon.ng-scope {
    position: relative;
}
span.icon_flag_topic {
    position: absolute;
    left: 976px;
}
```

But when I zoom it still messes up like usual. -_-

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Like @Paulie_D said, you should probably use percent, block-level containers and so on to get a responsive, non-breaking website. Or you could use a framework, like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: I dont use Bootstrap @WilliamBrochmann , i use angular material and material design lite as of now... im not in to bootstrap.

Comment: There should be formatting presets or instructions available on the mdl website. Use cards or some other preset for your layout and you won't have to bother with positioning.

Comment: Im not to sure @WilliamBrochmann . i use a great great variaty of libraries... It would really help though if you can help me out [here](https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/ng-fourm) though ;).

Comment: See the [mdl layout](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove all relative statements. Then you need some advanced flexbox styles. With `flex-wrap: wrap` you can keep things from falling of the screen on the left, as this will allow the content to be multi-line. Using `justify-content: flex-end` you can align everything nicely to the right, as you tried with relative positioning to accommodate larger screens.

Good luck with the nice project.

Comment: PS. I had access to the Cloud9 environment. Otherwise I would have never figured this out.

Comment: I tried looking into flexbox stuff.... but even when i look at it, it dosent help at all... For example the loading screen is a off when you rezize the browser.. I need to understand how to do this, in order to apply it everywhere. Btw Project is here: https://github.com/amanuel2/ng-forum

Answer (score 1):

When you use:

```
position: relative
```

You are positioning an element relative to its parent. So if the position of that parent element changes (for instance via a browser resize) then so too will elements positioned in this way.

I would recommend wrapping the items you wish to position in a containing element such as a div and give that element relative positioning with the child elements getting absolute positioning. Like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>

.parent{
    position:relative;
}

.child{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
}
```

Comment: +1 Good suggestion, but this might make things more complex. Following a layout structure like Twitter Bootstrap provides seems like a better approach, than absolute positioning.

Comment: Huh.. i never thought about this.. but im preety sure i was already doing this in past code?? would you be so kind to help me out [here](https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/ng-fourm)?

Comment: James, your way dosent seem to work.... I edited my question to show you it dosent work for some reason :/

Answer (score 0):

You have got to completely redo your layout approach. A quick fix for a site that is completely build the way you describe is to add a viewport with a fixed width to remove 'responsiveness':

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200">
```

PS. You can replace 1200 with any width at which things still look OK.

Comment: Please test on a mobile device or with the mobile device emulator in chrome (press F12 and select the small mobile icon).

Comment: I would strongly suggest you to follow this approach. This will help you for now and does not require you to understand any 'advanced' CSS. When your MVP is finished, evaluate it and only improve it if that is still required. Do not over-engineer it right now.

Comment: JoostS... this honestly does not work... Like im deas serious it dosent work.. Can you help me here? https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/ng-fourm